# z-index of <canvas> in IE 9 problem

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, internet-explorer-9, z-index

I am experiencing a strange issue with the z-index of a `<canvas>`; not rendering as the right layer in IE9.  Please take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xacto/MTUHX/

Here's how it should work:

- The red-outlined box should be hyperlinked and be the top layer.
- The cyan `<canvas>` should the next layer.
- The box with the green background should be on the bottom.

This works properly in Chrome, Firefox, and even IE8.  However, in IE9 the cyan `<canvas>` is the top layer and the red-outlined hyperlinked box is no longer clickable except for the small area at the bottom where it does not overlay the cyan `<canvas>`.

Here's another thing of note:  if you change the `<canvas>` to a `<div>` i.e. change the line:

```
var can = $('<canvas></canvas>').css({...
```

to

```
var can = $('<div></div>').css({...
```

It will work in IE9 as well. This leads me to believe this is a `<canvas>` related issue rather than just a z-index issue.

I've tried many combinations of z-indexes based on suggestions found around the web, but nothing seems to work.  If anyone has an answer to this, it would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.  Some may ask why the `<canvas>` is being added via JavaScript and why it is added as the first element of the `<body>`.  Without going into details, the 3rd party app which uses the `<canvas>` requires it to be added that way.

Comment: Hmm...I tried this on 2 separate machines with IE9 (one of them was a brand new installation of IE9) and both failed.  To clarify, everything within the red-outlined box needs to be hyperlinked, not just the red-outline, itself.

Comment: This won't fix the issue but it is worth mentioning. I am not sure if you are using the html5 doctype, but if you aren't then you cannot put a `<div>` inside an `<a>`.

Comment: This only looks 'wrong' when using Quirks Mode on IE9.

Comment: @phrogz: I have to disagree with you. I have tested it on Windows + IE9 in Standards Mode and it doesn't work as the op desires.

Comment: @tw16 You see the red-outlined box below the cyan in IE9 standards mode?

Comment: @phrogs: No. It is in the correct order that the op describes. The red-outlined box is on top of the cyan box, but only the border and the bottom part of it where there is no canvas is clickable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but for some reason the problem appears to be because there is no background set on your boxes.

If you set a `background-color` for either `#box2` or `#box3` the link becomes clickable.  Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/HFKMC/

So you can use:

```
.box2{
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.01); /* this is basically transparent */
}
```

By using rgba and setting a very low alpha value, you won't even notice it has been applied.

Comment: Odd problem for IE to have - but this fixed my problem with having a JQuery draggable div that needed to be in front of a canvas element.